# ReactJS: webpack Bundle.js not found(404)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set up a simple react project. I am using a webpack, I am geting an error GET http://localhost:3001/bundle.js 404 (Not Found) however bundle.js is generated in public folder

here is my package.json file

```
`{
  "name": "hello-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "simple react app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}`
```

here is server.js

```
var express = require('express');
// Create our app
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3001,function(){
  console.log('server is up on 3001');
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

my folder structure 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All of you guys.
I resolved issue, the problem was with runing a webpack command and then runing a server.

Comment: Thank You ! It worked for me. After running **npm run build** and after that running my server resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

because you have `bundle,js` in public folder, check the name again

Comment: you used the comma instead(`,`) of dot(`.`)

Comment: Thanks, Rishabh, It wasn't comma however it appears to be

Answer (score 0):

According to your folder structure, your 'bundle,js' contains comma (,) this should be dot(.) change your bundle.js name in your index.html if its wrong there. Or, go to your webpack-config file and check for 'output' file name, there must be some error. or, if you are creating it dynamically then change it there.

Comment: Thanks, Upasana, It wasn't comma however it appears to be